# Должно ли местоимение после именительного темы быть согласовано с ним в падеже?

Tags: пунктуация

**Люди — у них часто имеется целый спектр мнений...**
Можно ли так писать?
Или единственный верный вариант: **Люди — они имеют целый спектр мнений...**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если определять на слух, то правильным кажется только один вариант: ***Люди — они имеют целый спектр мнений...***
2. Если посмотреть правила, то эта тема есть в ПАС:

Однако при именительном темы, более тесно связанном с основным предложением, в котором имеется **личное или указательное местоимение** в качестве слова-отсылки, ставится **тире**: ***Тягач — он** как танк, только без башни* (газ.); ***Марченко — тот** был человек, золотой человек* (Каз.); ***Дорога в дождь — она** не сладость, **дорога в дождь — она** беда* (Евт.).

Сравнить: ***Слово! Язык!** Об этом нужно писать не короткие статьи, а страстные воззвания к писателям* (Пауст.).

[ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ ПРИ ИМЕНИТЕЛЬНОМ ТЕМЫ](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110#pp110)

Таким образом, если мы хотим изменить падеж, то именительный темы пишется отдельно от предложения, например: *Люди! У них часто имеется целый спектр мнений...*  Если же мы ставим тире, то нужно использовать  местоимение в И.п.

Comment: А как полагаете, можно ли тут ставить запятую и тире? Мне 'на глаз' кажется такая пунктуация верной. *Люди, — у них часто имеется целый спектр мнений...* У Розенталя про запятую и тире раскидано по куче параграфов, так что я, может, что-то не углядел.

Comment: Это уже не именительный темы, а сложное предложение? А интонация у вас здесь какая? Как вариант, здесь возможно понижение голоса перед подчеркнутой паузой (как бы размышлением). А единый знак (запятая и тире) довольно УНИВЕРСАЛЕН в своем применении. Так что при таком толковании можно допустить вариант. (Интернет работает нестабильно, сеть регулярно пропадает, увы.)

Comment: Я полагаю, что если рассматривать интонационно, тот тут и впрямь лучше будет восклицательный знак поставить. Либо многоточие, тоже вариант.

Comment: Я думаю, что у всех этих знаков разная интонация и смысловые оттенки. Восклицание — это особая тема. Многоточие возможно,  но  там тоже пауза с "другим" смыслом, чем здесь, Можно заменить:  А что люди — у них часто имеется целый спектр мнений...  И вот единый знак примерно такой же смысл передает.